# wget command in sudo crontab

Tags: raspbian-buster, cron

On my RPi Buster I am using `sudo crontab -e` to get image from http page:

```
*/1 * * * * /usr/bin/wget -b http://lutov.radionet.sk/phpmyadmin/inovec.jpeg -O /var/www/html/wp-content/uploads/inovec.jpeg -o /tmp/wget.log
```

content of /tmp/wget.log is this:

```
Resolving lutov.radionet.sk (lutov.radionet.sk)... 185.14.252.183
Connecting to lutov.radionet.sk (lutov.radionet.sk)|185.14.252.183|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 404 Not Found
2021-01-09 22:10:02 ERROR 404: Not Found.
```

The result is file with 0 size.

But when I run the command manually, through console, the file has size and picture is viewable.

```
sudo wget -b http://lutov.radionet.sk/phpmyadmin/inovec.jpeg -O /var/www/html/wp-content/uploads/inovec.jpeg
```

```
Resolving lutov.radionet.sk (lutov.radionet.sk)... 185.14.252.183
Connecting to lutov.radionet.sk (lutov.radionet.sk)|185.14.252.183|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 95174 (93K) [image/jpeg]
Saving to: ‘/var/www/html/wp-content/uploads/inovec.jpeg’

/var/www/html/wp-content/uploads/inovec 100%[=============================================================================>]  92.94K   524KB/s    in 0.2s    

2021-01-09 22:17:48 (524 KB/s) - ‘/var/www/html/wp-content/uploads/inovec.jpeg’ saved [95174/95174]
```

I can't find the problem for few hours. I tried several options to wget, but I have no clue where the problem can be... Thanks for answers!

inside of `/var/spool/cron/crontabs/root` is:

```
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
*/3 * * * * /usr/bin/php /var/www/html/weewx/airqualitydata.php >/dev/null 2>&1
*/5 * * * * wget "http://www.inoveckachata.sk/kamera/image.jpg" -O /var/www/html/wp-content/uploads/chata.jpg >/dev/null 2>&1
* * * * * wget "http://lutov.radionet.sk/phpmyadmin/inovec.jpeg" -O "/var/www/html/wp-content/uploads/inovec.jpeg" -o /tmp/wget.log
```

Yes, I want to run it as root, I think it is necessary(?), or can I simply run it as www-data? How? does www-data have cron? The file owner is www-data, just to add security.
The other file - image.jpg is always downloaded.
now it seems that it is working again, without changing anything? strange! I am confused and curious how long will it run.

Comment: I tried it. No change. What is strange, when once a time the picture is there, 
ls -la looks like this - look at the hour at inovec.jpeg. 
-rw-r--r-- 1 www-data www-data 131810 Jan 10 07:59 chata.jpg
-rw-r--r-- 1 www-data www-data 118787 Jan 10  2021 inovec.jpeg
is it possible, that i am using different wget on crontab as in terminal?

Comment: The `crontab` command runs an editor for a personal crontab of invoking user. With `sudo` you invoked it as root and therefore you edited a root's personal crontab, which is `/var/spool/cron/crontabs/root`. Please, show us what is now in this file? Also note, this means cron will run your wget command **as root**. Is this what you intended? And, last note. I added your command exactly like you do, with sudo crontab. It works, file downloaded and updated and as expected is **owned by root**. The only difference might be I don't have www-data, I just created all the path with mkdir -p as root.

Comment: So it is running. My conf was probably allright, maybe the server side? Thanks for help anyway!